# Accessing a mysql database from external host/ip? (ie: mysql workbench)

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, iptables, mysql-workbench

I have a mysql server running on x.x.x.x, and can access it internally no problem (of course). However when attempting to connect externally, ie using mysql workbench, or even from an external server, I get the error message "Host 'bla.bla.bla' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server".

I have done:

- `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO mysql@x.x.x.x IDENTIFIED BY "somepass";`
- And I have opened port 3306 in iptables.

Is there another fundamental security issue I am missing?

Comment: if `x.x.x.x` is your server IP and you have access grant from this IP only, tou can't connect from others ip

Comment: Thats what I figured, is there way to grant access from another host/ip?

Comment: grant privileges to `user@your.ip.or.%.for any.host`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to do

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO mysql@'bla.bla.bla' ...
```

The part after the `@` is the host from which the connection is coming, so you have allowed only connections coming from localhost. You need to allow access from each remote host necessary (or all hosts - `... mysql@'%' ...` - if applicable).

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh... thank you! "%" was the fix that was needed. I knew there was a way to grant global access. I am assuming this is not a good idea for a production server though?

Comment: Dont forget to use FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Answer (score 8):

To solve this you needed to perform the following commands:

```
mysql -u root -p
[enter in your password]
CREATE USER 'mysqluser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'aC0MPL3XPa33W0RD';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysqluser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the exactly similar situation.my MYSQL is installed on a centOS.
The path to Nirvana is as below.

1. bind-address: DID NOT WORK
2. grant permission: DID NOT WORK
3. Iptables when turned off: DID work.

SOLUTION:I went fishing into the iptables and made following changes:

1. Access the iptables using the command : vim /etc/sysconfig/iptables
2. If you find the below statements COMMENT them out by adding a '#' at the beginning of the line.

   -A INPUT -s 123.123.123.123/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT

   -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

   -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
3. Restart the iptables using the command: service iptables restart

Yep, that worked for me. Hope it is useful to someone.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps anybody except You but catch my upvote for Your effort and will to go back to stackoverflow and post this here in case! :)

Answer (score 3):

When I Got my server,even I had the same problem accessing the mysql from MySQL client application,
Then I granted the Mysql permission, with following query.

it worked Great

```
**GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_base.* TO db_user @'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'db_passwd';** 

db_base is the database Name
db_user is database User
db_passwd is the database password
```

Once you execute this flush it, by the following command
`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Suppose if you are looking to give privileges to access certain tables in the Database you can use the following command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_base.HELLOWORLD TO db_user @'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'db_passwd';
```

Where `HELLOWORLD` is the table Name

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting as user mysql? You might try running the GRANT query as : `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO mysql@x.x.x.x IDENTIFIED BY "somepass";`

Comment: just saw your edit. Ignore my query suggestion. What does your /etc/my.cnf look like?

Comment: Yea, I did that, and also created a secondary user and granted all to that user, to no avail. I do realize the problem is that i'm accessing a remote mysql server, i'm just wondering how to grant access to a remote user? (Ie, connecting to my remote server using mysql workbench on my laptop)

Comment: could be something to do with your my.cnf file? Do you have `bind-address=x.x.x.x` in there?

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that mysql workbench is trying the connect using the appropriate username? Have you [flushed the privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html) after running the grant command?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the ins and outs of security behind this `bind-address`thing, just learning by installing a debian server on a virtual-box machine.
This guest has a virtual network card set up as a bridge, so the rest of the house can see it. Its IP is 192.168.1.4.
From another computer (192.168.1.3), connection failed with `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`.
Set up `bind-address = 192.168.1.4` works fine.
(its own address, litterally)
It must be the interpretation of 127.0.0.1 inside a virtual config, not sure...

Answer (score -2):

Comment out the line:

```
bind-address = localhost
#bind-address = localhost < this is what it should look like.
```

in your MySQL my.conf file. It is normally located in /etc/mysql/my.conf.

Comment: No. If that were the case, he'd be getting a "connection refused" error from the host (because there would be no socket listening), not an "access denied" error from the MySQL server.