# Can't connect to remote MySQL server with error 61

Tags: mysql

When I tried to connect the remote MySQL server by using command line `mysql -h <remote-ip> -u any_existing_users -p` or any other mysql client such as phpmyadmin, it didn't work and the error hint was

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000) Can't connect to MySQL server on '<remote-ip>' (61)
```

But, when I tried `ssh <remote-ip>` and connected the MySQL locally by `mysql -u root -p`, there is no problem.

Here is part of the user table(`SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;`):

```
+------------------+----------------+
| User             | Host           |
+------------------+----------------+
| root             | %              |
| other_users      | <remote-ip>    |
| root             | localhost      |
+------------------+----------------+
```

Here is the iptable:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 255 
3    ACCEPT     esp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
4    ACCEPT     ah   --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
5    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         udp dpt:5353 
6    ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:631 
7    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:631 
8    ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
9    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22 
10   REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
11   ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:3306
```

So, what's the problem?

Comment: Please check my post here. It might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22637763/676508

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Check if your mysql server is listening on a socket with netstat:

```
netstat -tulpen
```

and search for 3306.

If not or if only on localhost, check my.cnf and search the `bind-address` line and change it to:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

then restart the server and try again.

Comment: A line shows ```tcp 0 0 :::3306 :::* LISTEN 100 1```. What does ```:::``` mean here? Does that mean mysql binds on an IPv6 address?

Comment: Seems like it, but I don't know cent os to be sure. Did you try to connect via ip on localhost? Connect via ssh and do "mysql -u user -p -h 127.0.0.1" or the public ip address of your server and test if you can connect. A simple "mysql -u user -p" could also connect through a socket file.

Comment: ```mysql -u user -p -h 127.0.0.1```, ```mysql -u user -p -h 0.0.0.0``` and ```mysql -u user -p -h <remote-ip>``` all work fine.@Kaffee

Comment: yeah ok so mysql server seems to be fine. now its either a firewall on your host, client or in the network.

Comment: Yes, it is. The network supports ipv6 yesterday, and the ```iptable``` just accepts request via ipv4 address. And the problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: bind-address = [your server's public IP address, or an IP address that your remote client can access via a private network]

Comment: bind-address = 0.0.0.0 works too. What does 0.0.0.0 do? Does it act as a wildcard for allowing the mysql server to bind to ANY ip address? Are there advantages to either, security or otherwise?

Comment: If you're getting `start: Job failed to start` when changing the bind-address to `0.0.0.0`, try commenting out that line entirely.

Comment: If getting blank '.cnf' files, verify the location of the '.cnf' file with: `mysql --help` as shown here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/mysql_remote.html Then, do the same for `bind-address` as above.

Comment: You may also need to add the `[mysqld]` header (in case it's missing) before you add the `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` line. Otherwise you'll get an error like `mysql: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 20.`

Comment: `netstat -tulpen` does not work on Windows 11, it just displays the options for arguments, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 32):

Check status:

```
netstat -tulpen
```

Modify your configuration:

```
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
# Edit:
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Enter mysql and give privileges:

```
mysql -umyuser -pmypassword
# Run:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%'IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
```

Restart mysql

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: While accurate, I would be more careful when granting privileges without a warning

Comment: this worked for me. but I just had to use sudo for step 2 and step 4

Comment: What can I do, when I don't have data in my.cnf file ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517064/remote-connection-to-mysql-with-public-ip-running-on-ubuntu-18-04-vps-from-pc

Answer (score 32):

With `MySql 5.7` they changed files so `bind-address` is now in:

```
/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

instead of:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Comment: same as above ^

Answer (score 18):

If you run MAMP, do not forget to allow access (mySQL panel, check "Allow network access to MySQL")

Comment: @andyp why do you think so? It looks like a (very short, but still) anwer to me.

Comment: @Jan: you're correct, I was too quick to dismiss this as a comment earlier

Comment: How to do this equivalent in MAMP 3.4? There is no MySQL panel anymore

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem just after installing Centos 7 on a server. I could´t access to it through Mysql Workbench in a remote computer.

The problem was in the firewall configuration. Eventually, the solution came when doing:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=mysql
```

And then, restart the firewall:

```
sudo systemctl restart firewalld
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be a problem related to firewall or try this:

GO to Server Admin -> MySQL -> Settings -> check: Allow Network Connections

Then restart MySQL

Comment: I'm using CentOS, how to allow the network connections for MySQL

Comment: centos using the `firewall-cmd` on 7.0+
try doing this on command line:
`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3306/tcp`
@WenhaoJi

make sure you have the `root` or adding `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the "Causes of Access-Denied Errors" from MySQL.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html

Possibile is there a failed configuration on your server or a other program is using the same port? Or is the server bind on "127.0.0.1"? Try changing the the my.cnf file.

Comment: There is no ```bind-address``` in my.cnf. When I add ```bind-address=<remote-ip>```, it doen't work at all.

Comment: Try giving at the start of the MySQL-Server a specific ip:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address

Comment: Link rot! Link rot!

Answer (score 1):

For MacOS:

```sh
mysql -uroot -p

mysql> use mysql;

# View user's host
mysql> select 'host' from user where user='root';
# Update host to '%'
mysql> update user set host='%' where user='root';

mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

```
vim /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

```
# Restart and reconnect MySQL
mysql.server restart
mysql -uroot -h0.0.0.0 -p
```