# After closing terminal without exiting "Connection refused" error. Django 1.8

Tags: python, mysql, django, terminal

Without any reason after I have closed terminal window without exiting and stoping server, the next time I run any command like python manage.py migrate/runserver/makemigrations I am getting the following traceback.I can't really understand what is wrong now?

EDIT:Also on 'mysql' command to enter into its interface `'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'`

EDIT2: I suppose it might be caused by MAMP which is also installed on my MAC

EDIT3: After I'v deleted MAMP. Not sure whether is was directly connected. Can't enter to mysql shell as well.

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

EDIT4!!:
I am using terminal on mac, so I applied this command
 sudo `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`
 and got back

```
ERROR! MySQL server process #1180 is not running! Starting MySQL..... ......... .........
```

after trying to start server

```
ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Air-Vitalij.local.pid).
```

restart command :

```
ERROR! MySQL server PID file could not be found!
```

EDIT5: following the recommendation from answer I tried change max_connections, but unsuccessfully :

```
mysql --help | grep "Default options" -A 1 
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

I tried all paths, but it's absent. And I can't find this file manually, I'v fund out that there is no my.cnf in MySQL for Mac. Also tried to delete MySQL and reinstall it - didn't help as well.

```
open -a Finder etc/mysql/my.cnf
The file /Users/TheKotik/djboy/etc/mysql/my.cnf does not exist.
```

[image][image]

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/q/16161889/2286762

Comment: @soupboy see the edit

Comment: did you search for the error you specified in edit?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/16325607/2286762

Comment: @soupboy yes, that error may be caused by a lot of different reasons, considering that before closing everything was fine, it may be a sort of bug

Comment: Ok. Which django and mysql versions you are using ?

Comment: @soupboy 5.7.13 MySQL, 1.8 Django

Answer (score 2):

consider increasing `max_connections` 
and restart mysql.

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart
```

For some reason the connection was not closed correctly when closing the terminal. Increasing max_connections will not cure it completely, but the hanging connection will eventually time-out.

Comment: @ixer how can I change max_connection if I have no access to mysql commands either?

Comment: it is a setting, usually in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` or similar location.

Comment: @Vinand, I dont have a mac, but there are a lot of answers to that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/mysql-my-cnf-location-on-os-x

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to restart your mysql process?. This can be useful when the mysql process is not shutdown correctly.

```
mysql.server restart
```