# MySql - ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '*dynamic IP Address*' (110)

Tags: php, mysql, linux, network-programming

I'm trying to connect remotely to my MySQL server. I'm getting the error above and not sure why.

What I've tried: 
 - Connecting to: *dynamic IP address*/phpmyadmin (works)
 - Granting the MySQL user all permissions
 - Commenting out bind-address and skip-networking in my.cnf.
 - Connecting to the server through localhost (works)

... I've looked at iptables but not really sure what I'm meant to be doing. Could do with some guidance here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161889/cant-connect-to-remote-mysql-server-with-error-61    and   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155665/cant-connect-to-mysql-database-using-external-ip-address

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97389/how-to-connect-mysql-database-in-my-vps-from-remote-machine    and   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/remotely-connecting-to-mysql