# i can't access to mysql database from c#

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

i have a web site and in it's `phpmyadmin` create a database and i want to connect to it from `c#`.

i use `MySQL connector for .NET` in visual studio  2010.

my `String Connection` is :

```
 server=158.58.185.197;database=porbarco_base;uid=****;pwd=****;CharSet=utf8;
```

but i can't connect to database and give an error : `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.`

How i can connect to this database.

i see many threads in `stackoverflow` but don't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you connect to the database at all from *that machine* using the given information?

Comment: So can you connect to it as that user from that machine outside of your code?

Comment: i can connect to database in my php code as localhost. i can connect to localhost mysql in my pc in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likelyhood is that the problem is less your C# and more remote access to MySQL

You need to check the following.

1. Is MySQL listening a network address.  Check your mysql configuration file.  Look for an entry for `bind address`.  if its set to `127.0.0.1` then you are just listening on localhost, change it to `0.0.0.0` and remember to restart the service
2. Is your linux firewall blocking remote access to the mysql port.
3. Does your mysql allow remote access for the specified user from a remote host. see [This link for an example of how to set this up](http://31bit.com/technology/86-mysql-database/302-how-to-grant-remote-access-to-a-mysql-database)

Comment: i don't access to `mysql` configuration files and `linux firewall`. i have an account in the site navidiranian.ir and use `direct admin` to administrate database and domain and so on. i found my problem and Explain it in below answer.

Comment: @MohammadRezaVahedi Your comment doesn't make sense. Name resolution will have nothing to do with it, you are using the ip address directly. It is not that. The likelihood is that your host provider doesn't support remote access to the MySQL database, which is not surprising as this is a big security hole. A quick look with nmap shows that port 3306 is not open on that server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access it directly using the IP address then the port 3306 needs to be open. Is the port open? If the application is hosted on the same server as the database then I would recommend using localhost to access it instead of the IP address.

Comment: port 3306 is open. my application is C# and server is linux base. i want to remotely access to database.

Comment: Try specifying the port right in the connection string as follows: Server=158.58.185.197;Port=3306;

Comment: Is it case sensitive? Try this version: Server=158.58.185.197;Port=3306;Database=porbarco_base;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;CharSet=utf8;

Comment: I do this and no change in Result.

Comment: Is your issue at all related to this posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915534/accessing-a-mysql-database-from-external-host-ip-ie-mysql-workbench

Comment: i found my problem!!! but i can't solve it. when i give my sites IP (www.porbarco.com) get me 158.58.185.197 but when i give recursively Name of IP get me ir1.navidiranian.com and navidiranian.com is my Host provider.

Comment: @MohammadRezaVahedi That is not going to be the case, all the reverse lookup tells you is that the number to name lookup records specify that `158.58.185.197` is `ir1.navidiranian.com`.  This wouldn't affect you access by IP.  The actual problem is that remote access to the MYSQL server is not enabled