# i am having difficulty on exporting issues on sql

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, resize, dbimport

i want to upload sql file into database but it is the size of the file is more. However server's phpmyadmin's import database limit is just 50mb so i am not able to upload it How can i increase this default size limit?

Answer (score 0):

Use SQLYog to import database..your problem will be solved surely.

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Yeah.. SQLYog is a database tool like phpmyadmin but opposite to the memory concern it handles larger file to be imported. Install it & with the credentials import the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the limits in the php.ini file. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958615/import-file-size-limit-in-phpmyadmin).

As an alternative I recommend using [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) rather than SQL Yog. It's freeware.

But with any external tool (Either SQL Yog and MySQL Workbench) you would have to make sure that [external access is allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915534/accessing-a-mysql-database-from-external-host-ip-ie-mysql-workbench) for your user on your database server instance.

*Please note: You have possibly overlooked this, but you mention 'exporting' in your question title, but then 'importing' in the actual question.*